# How to realize Digital fill light in Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, graphics

I want to realize the function of fill-light by use OpenCV, but There have some problem. Black part of pics is too dark, Photos become blurred, i don't know how to Optimization code。that my code:

V, value, 0~100, increase the amplitude of the brightness.

S,Scope, 0~255,   dark is all less than S.

increase exposure to light dark photos increment, unchanged, so to see more details of the dark.

m_imgOriginal: original image ,type:Mat

m_imgNew: new image , clone from m_imgOriginal ,type:Mat

```
int OpenCVClass::AddExposure(int v, int s)
```

{

```
int new_r = v*m_mean_val.val[0] / 150;
int new_g = v*m_mean_val.val[1] / 150;
int new_b = v*m_mean_val.val[2] / 150;

for (int y = 0; y < m_imgOriginal.rows; y++)
{
    auto ptr = m_imgOriginal.ptr<uchar>(y);
    auto qtr = m_imgNew.ptr<uchar>(y);
    for (int x = 0; x < m_imgOriginal.cols; x++)
    {

        int mean = (ptr[0] + ptr[1] + ptr[2]) / 3;

        if (mean <= s)
        {



                int r = ptr[0] + new_r;
                qtr[0] = r>255 ? 255 : r;
                int g = ptr[1] + new_g;
                qtr[1] = g>255 ? 255 : g;
                int b = ptr[2] + new_b;
                qtr[2] = b>255 ? 255 : b;
                int newMean = (qtr[0] + qtr[1] + qtr[2]) / 3;
                if (newMean > s)
                {
                    int nr = ptr[0] + (s - mean) ;
                    int ng = ptr[1] + (s - mean) ;
                    int nb = ptr[2] + (s - mean) ;

                    qtr[0] = nr>255 ? 255 : nr;
                    qtr[1] = ng>255 ? 255 : ng;
                    qtr[2] = nb>255 ? 255 : nb;

                }



        }

        else
        {


            qtr[0] = ptr[0];
            qtr[1] = ptr[1];
            qtr[2] = ptr[2];




        }
        ptr += 3;
        qtr += 3;
    }
    RenderBuffer(m_imgNew, m_displayBuffer);
}
return 0;
}
```

Optimization  before

[image]

Optimization  after

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest to calculate a luminance value for each pixel, when testing agains '`s`'. I mean calculate '`mean`' a different way (see this link on how to calculate luminance):
http://www.niwa.nu/2013/05/math-behind-colorspace-conversions-rgb-hsl/

Second, you are dealing with an 8 bit per channel image, don't expect near-or-perfect dark pixels to have any extra detail when you make them "brighter", they will just become grey or whiter.

Third, when "adding" brightness, I suggest using the HSL representation of pixel color values and increasing the luminance. In pseudocode:

```
1) Convert pixel color from RGB to HSL.
2) Increase luminance (or 'lightness').
3) Convert back pixel color to RGB.
```